# Laravel + October CMS, combined stylesheets doesn't interpreter as CSS

Tags: laravel, nginx, octobercms

I'm trying to run local project from git repository on Ubuntu 18 + Nginx. On frontend files from combined assets with names like "31bf092dab0286a768e84f61021e617e-1527088735" without extension, doesn't interpretered as CSS or JS.
In Chrome page loads without styles and Chrome showing error: "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://example.test/combine/31bf092dab0286a768e84f61021e617e-1527088735"."
What Nginx setting can ruin it all?

My config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.test *.example.test;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;
```

}

server {

```
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/localhost.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/localhost.key;

ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;

set $root_path /var/www/newemotion.test/web/;

root $root_path;

index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name example.test *.example.test www.example.test;

gzip on;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_disable "msie6";
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;

location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|pdf|ppt|txt|bmp|rtf|js|woff|ttf|otf|woff2)$ 
{
    expires 7d;
}

if (!-e $request_filename)
{
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 break;
    break;
}
rewrite themes/.*/(layouts|pages|partials)/.*.htm /index.php break;
rewrite uploads/protected/.* /index.php break;



location / {
    location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
        try_files /does_not_exists @php;
    }
}

    location ~ ^/favicon\.ico { try_files $uri /index.php; }
location ~ ^/sitemap\.xml { try_files $uri /index.php; }
location ~ ^/robots\.txt { try_files $uri /index.php; }
location ~ ^/humans\.txt { try_files $uri /index.php; }

## Let nginx return 404 if static file not exists
location ~ ^/storage/app/uploads/public { try_files $uri 404; }
location ~ ^/storage/app/media { try_files $uri 404; }
location ~ ^/storage/temp/public { try_files $uri 404; }

location ~ ^/modules/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
location ~ ^/modules/.*/resources { try_files $uri 404; }
location ~ ^/modules/.*/behaviors/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
location ~ ^/modules/.*/behaviors/.*/resources { try_files $uri 404; }
location ~ ^/modules/.*/widgets/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
location ~ ^/modules/.*/widgets/.*/resources { try_files $uri 404; }
location ~ ^/modules/.*/formwidgets/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
location ~ ^/modules/.*/formwidgets/.*/resources { try_files $uri 404; }
location ~ ^/modules/.*/reportwidgets/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
location ~ ^/modules/.*/reportwidgets/.*/resources { try_files $uri 404; }

location ~ ^/plugins/.*/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
location ~ ^/plugins/.*/.*/resources { try_files $uri 404; }
location ~ ^/plugins/.*/.*/behaviors/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
location ~ ^/plugins/.*/.*/behaviors/.*/resources { try_files $uri 404; }
location ~ ^/plugins/.*/.*/reportwidgets/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
location ~ ^/plugins/.*/.*/reportwidgets/.*/resources { try_files $uri 404; }
location ~ ^/plugins/.*/.*/formwidgets/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
location ~ ^/plugins/.*/.*/formwidgets/.*/resources { try_files $uri 404; }
location ~ ^/plugins/.*/.*/widgets/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
location ~ ^/plugins/.*/.*/widgets/.*/resources { try_files $uri 404; }

location ~ ^/themes/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
location ~ ^/themes/.*/resources { try_files $uri 404; }

location @php {
        #fastcgi_index index.php;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.ph(?:p\d*|tml))(/?.+)$;
        #try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
}
```

}

I have tryed to write default config from October CMS documentation. nothing helps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in memcached, i disabled it and set caching type as file in .env file.

Answer (score 0):

The mime type is set incorrectly as nginx uses the file extension for setting the mime type. To be able to set the mime type correctly, you will either need to use a file extension or alternatively set the default mime type for a directory.

To set the default mime type for a directory, use the following location block

```
location ~ css{
   default_type text/css;
}

location ~ js{
   default_type application/javascript;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Nick, but that was first what i did. Thanks for your help, but i already solve it.